# LinQ with CROSS APPLY and ORDER BY

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

If I want to show an main element along with information from the first underlying element, then a CROSS APPLY seems to be the most performant solution in SQL.

However when I write for example this LinQ query:

```
    from mm in a
    from qcr in b
        .Where(x => x.MasterID == mm.MasterID)      
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Priority)
        .Take(1)
    select new
    {
        mm.MasterID,
        mm.ColumnA,
        mm.ColumnB,
        mm.ColumnC,
        qcr.ColumnD,
        qcr.ColumnE,
        qcr.ColumnF,
    };
```

The result query looks like this:

```
FROM a AS [t0]
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1) [t1].[ColumnD], [t1].[ColumnE], [t1].[ColumnF], [t1].[Priority]
    FROM b AS [t1]
    WHERE [t1].[MasterID] = ([t0].[MasterID])
    ORDER BY [t1].[Priority] DESC
    ) AS [t2]
ORDER BY [t2].[Priority] DESC
```

The problem is the second ORDER BY that tries to sort the main result by Priority, this causes heavy performance issues (if I remove the ORDER BY manually in the SQL the whole query is 10 times faster).

I already tried overwriting the sorting by calling OrderByDescending again, but it only adds the columns to the Priority column instead of removing it from the sorting and doesn't improve performance.

Is there any way to write a CROSS APPLY in LinQ without it trying to sort everything by the column that's sorting by in the inner select of the CROSS APPLY?

Comment: Added, it's linq-to-sql (for the example above I simply used LinQPad 5 for).

Comment: Not much yo can do then. Use Entity Framework if you can.